# iOS left UIBarButtonItem with custom view makes the default back button appear below

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have the following setup:

CustomNavigationController.h:

```
@interface CustomNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end
```

CustomNavigationController.m:

```
@interface CustomNavigationController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *burgerBarButtonItem;

@end

@implementation CustomNavigationController

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){

        self.delegate = self;

        UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
        [customView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        UIView *anotherCustomView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
        [anotherCustomView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        self.backBarButtonItem   = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:customView];
        self.burgerBarButtonItem   = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:anotherCustomView];

    }

    return self;
}


-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{

    [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:@[self.backBarButtonItem, self.burgerBarButtonItem]];

    viewController.navigationItem.title = @"My custom title";

}

@end
```

I am initializing this using a storyboard. The root view controller has nothing but a button that pushes other view controllers onto the navigationControllers' stack.

The 2 custom `UIBarButtonItem` views are shown and behaving as expected. However, when I push a new view controller, a mysterious back button appears below the left-most barButtonItem. This seems to only happen when I have a custom title added. If I remove the line `viewController.navigationItem.title = @"My custom title";`, then it is working as expected.

Root view controller:

[image]

Any subsequent view controller:

[image]

I am assuming that since I add a custom leftBarItems property that will override the default back button, but if I am to add a title as well - seems to not be the case. Also, this only happens if I am initializing my `UIBarButtonItem`s with `initWithCustomView`, if I am using a standard `UIBarButtonItem` or `initWithImage` it works fine.

How can I make sure the back button does not show ? Tested on iOS 7, iOS 8, using ARC and autolayout.

**Edit:**

When I do navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES; either in `viewDidLoad` of the view controller or in `willShowViewController` this is what happens: (note the dots - they appear and fade out)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add

`viewController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;`

to your

`-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: I tried doing this already but it doesn't work too. When I do a subsequent push I can still see the back button fading away to the left. @Michael Platt check edits.

Comment: Agreed... What are the currently 'empty" views going to be, this problem goes away when using either... `initWithImage: style: target: action:` or `initWithTitle: style: target: action:`

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: I am guessing the buttons are not going to be empty red UIViews. If you are going to use an image use the first method I mentioned to init the UIBarButton, if you just want a word use the second. Both these methods, when used with the hiesBackButton method, solve the problem.

Comment: I want to use a custom view with custom elements inside, I wouldnt post the question otherwise.